# chart.js fixed bar width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

I am using Chart.js as my charting library. I have created horizontalBar chart.

I need to set the width of individual bar in the chart.

I did not found anything specific in chartjs documentation but while looking at source code I found the option `barThickness` which is setting the fixed bar width

But as number of rows increase, instead of increasing the height of the chart, the bar are colliding with each other. Please check fiddle for example:

https://jsfiddle.net/orhp0zLg/

Is there any way we can increase the height of the chart instead of letting the bars collide with each other?

Answer (score 2):

The `barThickness` property is a fixed width, as you noticed in your issue.

However, you have an other property called `barPercentage` which is a multiplier of the max width of your bars.
You should set `berPercentage` to a value (*let's say `0.95`*) and you'll always have the same format, no matter how many bars you have :

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.95,
        }]
    }
}
```

---

Here is your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orhp0zLg/1/) with the fix and here are the results with first 7 values and then 12 :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there also exist alternate way to fix the width of the bar and increase the height of the chart. May be by clearing the graph completely and setting the height  of the canvas and then re-render the the graph.

Comment: @user2692032 This answer uses the Chart.js built-in property. If you want a solution like you told, you should try asking another question about dynamic `css` and `canvas`.